отсутствуют экземпляры перегруженная функция "getline", соответствующие списку аргументов
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <vector>
#include <list>
#include <map>
#include <set>
#include <deque>
#include <string>


using namespace std;

int retrieve_text() {
    
    string fileName;
    cout << "Введите название файла" << endl;
    cin >> fileName;

    ifstream textFile(fileName.c_str(), ios::in);

    if (!textFile.is_open()) {
        cerr << "Ошибка чтения файла";
        exit(-1);
    }
    else{ cout << "Файл открыт"; }
    
    string textline;
    while (getline(textFile, textline, "\n")) { // почему ошибка?
        //...
    }
}

int main()
{
    //...
}


Прочтите внимательно описание функции. Какой тип третьего аргумента?
Как правильно записать значение типа char?
while (getline(textFile, textline, '\n')) { // почему ошибка?


Проблема в том, что VS не понимает, что за функция getline, вне зависимости от его аргументов.

Еще раз и медленно, как для депутата. Вы вместо символа передаете строку (указатель на массив символов). Замените двойные кавычки на одинарные, и код скомпилируется. Проверено именно на Visual C++.
